# Conversion of Numpy datetime64 in C API

Tags: python, c, numpy

How do you use a datetime64 passed from Python in C? I found some deprecated functions in the Numpy headers like PyArray_DatetimeToDatetimeStruct() but can't find anything relating to datetime64.

It seems like it is an array of integers along with some metadata on the backend but if so, how do you determine the units?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25033711/694576

Comment: In one sense it is a standard array, with 8 bytes per item.  It's the array `dtype` that handles that handles conversions.  For example `x.tolist()` produces a list of Python `datetime` objects.  It looks like the units information is in the `dtype.str`, `'<M8[us]'`.

Comment: looks like most of the `numpy` `datetime` manipulation is located in `numpy/numpy/core/src/multiarray/datetime.c`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those wondering how to do this in the future, here is the solution I ended up with.

Pass the datetime64 as an int64 from Python:

```
dt = np.datetime64(datetime.utcnow())
my_C_func(dt.astype(np.int64))
```

The decoding in C is derived from the source of gmtime(). This code assumes that the datetime is in microseconds which you can determine by checking the dtype (thanks @hpaulj). `start` is the datetime64 coming from Python.

```
inline int
is_leapyear(uint64_t year)
{
    return (year & 0x3) == 0 && /* year % 4 == 0 */
           ((year % 100) != 0 ||
            (year % 400) == 0);
}
#define YEARSIZE(year) (is_leapyear(year) ? 366u : 365u)

...

uint64_t us_per_day = 1000ull * 1000ull * 60ull * 60ull * 24ull;
register uint64_t dayclock = start % us_per_day;
register uint64_t dayno = start / us_per_day;

uint64_t year = 1970ull;

uint64_t us = dayclock % 1000000ull;
uint64_t sec = (dayclock / 1000000ull) % 60ull;
uint64_t minute = (dayclock % 3600000000ull) / 60000000ull;
uint64_t hour = dayclock / 3600000000ull;
while (dayno >= YEARSIZE(year))
{
    dayno -= YEARSIZE(year);
    year++;
}

uint64_t day = dayno + 1;
```

If you don't need anything more accurate than seconds you could simply do this:

```
uint64_t other_start = start / 1000000ull;
struct tm* ptm;
ptm = gmtime((time_t*)&other_start);

printf("\tGMTIME VERSION:\n");
printf("\tyear: %d\n", ptm->tm_year);    
printf("\tday: %d\n", ptm->tm_yday);
printf("\thours: %d\n", ptm->tm_hour);
printf("\tminutes: %d\n", ptm->tm_min);
printf("\tsec: %d\n", ptm->tm_sec);
```

Of course the us portion can then be obtained separately:

```
uint64_t us = source % 1000000ull;
```

Comment: Forgot extra 000 zeroes in divider, as gmtime works with seconds (as said in text). But given divider gives millis. Proper is / 1000000000ull

Comment: This is not a useful answer; you asked how to use "datetime64 passed from Python in C", and this answer just presumes that we can change the calling code. The rest of the code ignores that datetime64 can have different base units. The use of `gmtime` is the way to go though even if you need sub-second precision, just use `dayclock % 1000000ull` for the the fractional part. Teaching to re-implement `gmtime` with a loop is counter-educational.

Answer (score 1):

A `numpy.datetime64` type is implemented in C with the `PyDatetimeScalarObject` structure. It holds a number and the units that the number counts, and it can be accessed as follows:

```
if(!PyArray_IsScalar(obj, Datetime))
    ; // error

PyDatetimeScalarObject *datetime = (PyDatetimeScalarObject*)obj;
const char *unit;
switch(datetime->obmeta.base) {
case NPY_FR_D: unit = "days"; break;
case NPY_FR_s: unit = "seconds"; break;
case NPY_FR_ns: unit = "nano-seconds"; break;
// ...
}
printf("%lld %s\n", datetime->obval, unit);
```