# How can you get the numpy datetime64 resolution from an array using the C api?

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray, c-api

When writing python code for numpy arrays you can see the resolution of a given datetime64 array using its `dtype` for example

```
>>> np.array(np.datetime64('2001-01-01'), np.datetime64('2001-01-02')).dtype
dtype('<M8[D]')
>>> np.array(np.datetime64('2001-01'), np.datetime64('2001-02')).dtype
dtype('<M8[M]')
```

The `dtype` specifies if the resolution is days or months. But using the numpy C API I cant seem to figure out what struct member holds this resolution information.

```
// obj is the numpy array
// e.g. np.array(np.datetime64('2001-01-01'), np.datetime64('2001-01-02'))
PyArray_Descr* descr = PyArray_DESCR((PyArrayObject*)obj);
// descr->kind == 'M' for datetime objects
// descr->elsize == 8 for 64bit 
// ??? is the [M] / [D] resolution for a numpy array of datetime64 objects?
```

I found this previous post on converting scalar datetime64 objects [Conversion of Numpy datetime64 in C API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41642874/conversion-of-numpy-datetime64-in-c-api) . But for my use case it is also valid to pass an empty array that has one of these types such as `np.array([], dtype=np.dtype('datetime64[D]'))`, which means converting an element to a scalar to figure out the resolution information may not be possible.

Does anyone know what struct field I should be looking into or what functions I can use in the numpy C API to figure out this resolution information?

Comment: https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/c-api/datetimes.html talks about a PyArray_DatetimeMetaData struct and a NPY_DATETIMEUNIT field.

Comment: Yeah I've seen those, I just can't figure out how to get them from the base ndarray object. All of the struct members on the base PyArrayObject are of different types and I can't seem to find a function that returns that struct from anything.

Comment: `arr=np.array([np.datetime64('2001-01-01'), np.datetime64('2001-01-02')])` has the same `[D]` dtype.     Note - I added `[]` to your comment line.